# Как запушить изменения одной ветки в другую не принимая изменения второй ветки, но иметь возможность модифицировать её?

Tags: python, git, github

У меня есть ветка `main` и ветка `deploy`. На деплое есть отдельные файлы для деплоя. Я сделал изменения в главной ветке и теперь хочу их запушить и в главную ветку, и в ветку деплой. Но проблема в том, что я должен принять сначало изменения ветки деплой, чего мне не нужно, так как на деплое настройки й файлы для деплоя, которые не нужны в главной ветке. Можно как-то запушить на деплой не принимая изменений(новые файли), при этом сохраняя некоторый код, который есть только на второй ветке и изменить другие файлы на этой ветке? Было бы очень удобно принимать эти изменения с главной ветки на деплое с помощью построчного конфликта, принимая или отклоняя изменение.

Comment: Следует переключиться на ветку deploy и сделать rеbase или merge. Если есть конфликты, то их необходимо будет разрешить. А вообще похоже, что вместо вытки должен был быть отдельный репозиторий.

Answer (score 0):

Если есть что-то чего не должно быть в репозитории, то это нужно добавить в .gitignore.
Если нужно взять изменения из одного коммита и применить их в другой ветке, то можно использовать `git cherry-pick`